# How do I replace a string in this code example so it runs through a whole column of strings from my df?

Tags: string, dataframe, data-augmentation

Let's say I have the code below, but I don't want to have to manually enter different strings after the t.augment.  How do I change it so it will run down a list of strings from my dataframe and generate output as a new list?

```
    import nltk
    nltk.download('punkt')
    nltk.download('wordnet')
    t = Wordnet()
    t.augment('In the afternoon, John is going to town')
```